# Регистрация пользователя в две таблицы в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно модернизировать функцию регистрации, что бы поле username записывалось еще и в другую таблицу в БД, в моем случае это `{$this->dbSmot}`, то есть нужно, как то соединить две таблицы.

```
 public function register( $id, $password, $other = array() ){
    if( $this->userExists($id) || (isset($other['email']) && $this->userExists($other['email'])) ){
        return "exists";
    }else{
        $randomSalt = $this->rand_string(20);
        $saltedPass = hash('sha256', "{$password}{$this->passwordSalt}{$randomSalt}");

        if( count($other) == 0 ){
            /* Если другие поля не указаны, выполните запрос по умолчанию */
            $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$this->dbtable}` (`username`, `password`, `password_salt`) VALUES(:username, :password, :passwordSalt)");
        }else{
            /* если есть другие поля для добавления значения, сделайте запрос и свяжите значения в соответствии с ним */
            $keys    = array_keys($other);
            $columns = implode(",", $keys);
            $colVals = implode(",:", $keys);
            $sql     = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `{$this->dbtable}` (`username`, `password`, `password_salt`, $columns) VALUES(:username, :password, :passwordSalt, :$colVals)");
            foreach($other as $key => $value){
                $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
                $sql->bindValue(":$key", $value);
            }
        }
        /* Привязка значений по умолчанию */
        $sql->bindValue(":username", $id);
        $sql->bindValue(":password", $saltedPass);
        $sql->bindValue(":passwordSalt", $randomSalt);
        $sql->execute();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: в чем проблема сделать еще один Insert в другую таблицу ?

Comment: я пробовал но не получается, напишите пример, пожалуйста

Comment: покажите как пробовали

Comment: `:$colVals` это видимо вы так пробовали?

Comment: А как получиться?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Нужно модернизировать функцию регистрации, что бы поле username записывалось еще и в другую таблицу в БД, в моем случае это {$this->dbSmot}, то есть нужно, как то соединить две таблицы.

Вот такой вариант вставки должен работать.

```
$sql = "
  INSERT INTO `{$this->dbtable}` (`username`, `password`, `password_salt`)
         VALUES(:username, :password, :passwordSalt);
  INSERT INTO `another_table`(`username`) VALUE(:username);
";
```

Comment: А что комментарий удалили, все работает же?

Comment: @Владислав https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Спросил на свою голову -6 репутации, за что?

Comment: @Владислав с определённой высоты/полёта/опыта, ваш вопрос и мой на него ответ, кажутся не уместными, так как (можно найти в гугл и т.д. и т.п.), добро пожаловать на SO.